# How to create custom dialog box using VScode API

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create custom dialog box using VScode API.Is there any method to achieve this?
Currently I know vscode.window.showInputBox() method but this opens in command pallet.
I am looking for method similar to vscode.window.showWarningMessage() which has capability to have certain fields/controls to accept user input.

Thanks & Regards,
Ajay

Comment: If the dialog does something useful it must have a back end, an extension, use a webview

Comment: I know web view is an option but for one or two input control i do not want to use web view..